# Making an attendance system in Wordpress with CPT

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a kidscamp website using Wordpress. I've the 'Students' and 'Attendance' CPT created with some custom fields (using ACF) and now I want to do the attendance system.

I thought the best solution is creating an admin page that shows an input and a dropdown of every student inside a form using a custom loop.

My doubt is how can I create and process this form to create (or modify if there is a previous result) the 'Attendance' CPTs for every 'Student' input?

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is attendance? Like one post per event where you map which students attended exactly this event? The most simple solution in this case would be to add a `Post field` limited to "Students" post-type with multi-select allowed. This would enable you to easily update the list of students per event / month / year (whatever applies here).

Comment: I want to have a record of each student's attendance during each day.